# Dangerous Request.Path - but only at root of asp.net webforms site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm going through a long penetration test report and have fixed the vast majority of problems, but I'm stuck with one particular problem which really should be fixed by some previous work.

In order to stop verbose error messages, I decided to intercept HttpExceptions in global.asax as in:

```
    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       Dim exc As Exception = Server.GetLastError
       If (exc.GetType Is GetType(HttpException)) Then
           If exc.Message.Contains("potentially dangerous Request.Path") Then
               Response.Redirect("~/")
           End If
       End If
    End Sub
```

Now yes, this is slightly filthy, but it works and intercepts any throws of this particular exception.  For instance pointing a browser at https://test.mysite.org/%3cscript%3e_q_q=%27%29%28%27%3c/script%3e then the site detects the exception, swallows it and redirects to the homepage with no error page shown.

However, if I go to the same URL but with the slash between host and payload removed - that is to say, https://test.mysite.org%3cscript%3e_q_q=%27%29%28%27%3c/script%3e - then the exception throws and you see the standard IIS HTTP 500 page with the dreaded verbose exception.  I'm not sure exactly why this is the case and what I can do to intercept it - in all other circumstances, the fix in place works perfectly well.

What can/should I do in order to intercept this exception in the stated case?  I have a terrible feeling it's something going on in the pipeline below where the HttpApplication lives...

Comment: Which framework are you on. If I try that I go straight to google! (from localhost.) They're basically the same error, can you just skip the check for `If exc.Message.Contains` and go right to redirect?

Comment: I'm in ASP.NET Webforms, .NET 4.5  If the URL is missing the '/' as stated, it doesn't hit the exception handler.  That's the entire point.  The thing that's sending you to Google is your browser, not my code - someone exploiting this issue in the wild won't be doing it in-browser.

Comment: Ah, i guess you threw me when you said "the exception throws."